# Are kernel-mode functions and kernel modules valid code-golf answers?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

In general, user-mode processes have a much richer API environment available (through stdlib, and other libraries you can possibly import), than does (Linux) kernel-mode code.  However there are some situations I can think of where it would conceivably be shorter to give a kernel-mode [c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) answer than a user-space process or function.

- Can an entire kernel module (including all the `module_init()`, etc boiler plate) be submitted as an answer?  If so, I assume the golf score would be for the code for the entire module.
- Can a function that gets called from kernel mode be submitted?  In this case the golf score would just be for the function on its own.  If a function is submitted, then it should be accompanied by the associated module boilerplate needed to run it, as well build instructions.

I/O is not as straightforward as for userspace processes.  Some possibilities are:

- module args for input
- `printk()` into the "dmesg" buffer for output
- procfs for input and output